# Why the java version returned in the terminal on my Mac OS is still 1.8.0_25 after I have updated it to 1.8.0_31?

Tags: java, macos

I've updated the Java version to 1.8.0_31 on my Mac from the Java Control Panel (the Java Preferences).

But when I executed command "java -version" in the terminal, it still shows the old version:

```
Minggaos-MacBook-Pro:~ minggaoxi$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
Minggaos-MacBook-Pro:~ minggaoxi$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25
```

Why? I think the lastest version should be 1.8.0_31.
How can I let the returned version in the terminal be the latest installed version?
My Mac OS version is OS X Yosemite 10.10.1.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe both are installed and in PATH the version 1.8.0_25 is found first?

Comment: The java control panel updates the JRE used for interactive applications, not the JRE included in the JDK. You need to upgrade that separately.

Comment: This is off topic.  Installing software is not a programming problem ... even if the software you are trying to install is Java.